# Tags Antarctica and Antarctic: request merge

Tags: discussion, support, tags

Antarctic currently has more posts but Antarctica seems more correct.

Comment: They have different meanings... one being a region and the other being a continent.  I see some questions using the wrong tag, but I don't see the issue of keeping both tags.